# Would these C-pointer operations cause problems?

Tags: c, pointers, theory, dereference, lvalue

Let's say I've got that:

```
char *p = NULL;
```

I'm sure this one would be a problem as I'd be dereferencing a `NULL` pointer:

```
*p = 16;
```

On the other hand, I think this one would be OK for I'd be getting the address of *p which is not `NULL` itself:

```
char **pp = &p;
```

Am I right in both cases?

Comment: `s/the address of *p which/the address of p which/`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you are. Although the value of p is NULL, it still has a valid address, so you may pass its reference.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you are correct in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in both cases. Just to add a simple clarification. Though you assign

```
char **pp = &p;
```

You still cant access **pp, because it is still has NULL. But you can safely access *pp.